# Provide the actual HTTP GET request within the response

Tags: java, nginx

I would like to provide the actual get request in a response. I am free to choose between placing that information into the header or the body of the response.
The current project setup includes:

- Nginx as reverse proxy
- Spring boot application

which are potential candidates to put in that logic.

Request:

```
GET http://localhost/api/users/2/photos/2
```

Response:

```
BODY {"some": "values",
"_request": "GET http://localhost/api/users/2/photos/2"}
```

or

```
HEADERS "custom-header-get-request": "GET http://localhost/api/users/2/photos/2"
BODY {"some": "values"}
```

I can easily add the information to the response of each Responseobject within the Controllers of the spring boot application. This approach is quite cumbersome, as it leads to a lot of codechanges and allways needs to be in mind that each Controller should take care of providing the requestinformation to the response, achieving the first solution.

Which other options do i have?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Sry for the confusion. I somehow commited the partial of the question while stil editing.

Comment: Why? The requester knows what he asked for. He doesn't need to be reminded.

Comment: Why: I was trying to put the request into the response so the client can correlate the response to a given request (which is allways the case since it is synchronised). My initial thought was, to put the response with the request into a socket. This should provide a way to get an existing api able to work with an async request writing the answers to a socket.
While describing it, i do see that i mix the synchronised controller with a asynch communication model. I didn't want to change the depending frameworks with a newer spring version to use webflux, as it currently "general available"